# Podcast online sync service

Tags: podcasts

I download and listen to podcasts on 2 different computers. I would like so somehow sync the metadata such that, when I subscribe to a feed it gets subscribed on my other computer also. When I've downloaded a podcast it gets marked as downloaded on the other machine also.

Is there a software + webservice combination that will allow me to do this. That will save its doings to the cloud and update it also? My one machine is Windows and the other one Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never looked into it, but I know that the [gpodder](http://gpodder.org/index.html) podcast client does [cloudy things](http://gpodder.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying it out now, and it seems to be just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a streaming service like [Stitcher](http://stitcher.com)?

Comment: Cool! It happen to support my blackberry. But I think I pay on demand when streaming audio instead of a fixed rate. Joys of living in south africa.